# Google Universal Analytics Remarketing and Dynamic Remarketing

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-ads-api

I am trying to implement remarketing, dynamic remarketing **and** Adwords conversion tracking within my e-commerce website. The problem I am facing is there seems to be a flurry of information regarding the implementations of these features where one source (mostly Google's own developers portal) says I can use Google Universal Analytics to all of these but also says that I should use the Adwords tags directly. I am incredibly confused by it all. If there is an expert out there that knows how I can implement these things using only Universal Analytics I'd be most grateful.

What I have so far is the standard Universal Analytics script on my website and have enabled displayfeatures:

```
ga("require", "displayfeatures");
```

This as far as I am aware will enable remarketing. But I have read nothing about also enabling dynamic remarketing. Does it enable both? I have also setup custom dimension on GA so I should be able to capture these using the following:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', '123');
ga('set', 'dimension2', 'product');
```

My confusion extends to how I track Adwords conversions through Universal Analytics. More specifically how I would push up `google_conversion_label`, `google_conversion_language`, `google_conversion_format`, etc... From what I gather I may only be able to do this via the Adwords tag. Am I barking up the wrong tree trying to use GA when I should be using the Adwords tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call

```
google_trackConversion({
  'google_conversion_id': ID GOES HERE,
  'google_conversion_language': 'en',
  'google_conversion_format': '3',
  'google_conversion_label': 'gzTWCJb7wl4Q6quR4QM',
  'google_conversion_currency': 'GBP',
  'google_remarketing_only': false
});
```

passing in all the relevant information. This is not part of Universal Analytics but AdWords Remarketing Tag